# Remove "How to Ask Questions in Private Beta" from the Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

During my regular perusal of Stack Overflow's Help Center<sup>*</sup>, I was surprised to see [detailed instructions on "How to Ask Questions in Private Beta"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta):

[image]

This is confusing for two reasons:

1. Stack Overflow is not, nor has ever been, in "private beta".
2. There is another ["How to Ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which is the main one that we want people to read<sup>*</sup>, and we wouldn't want them to get confused and accidentally read<sup>*</sup> the wrong one.

I'm guessing that this is a mistake, and meant to be shown only on sites currently in "private beta" as a *replacement* for the main "How to Ask" page.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Hah! Who am I kidding? We all know that nobody bothers to read all of that text!</sub>

Comment: Maybe we got demoted?

Comment: We *are* basically failing all the original metrics for a site's graduation, and many of these guidelines, as well. We didn't get the site *I* built.

Comment: @CodyGray SE started with us, so naturally we wouldn't meet all requirements! We existed before Area 51. :D

Comment: No we're still in private beta. Only Jon Skeet is answering in the graduated version of Stack Overflow.

Comment: That "how to ask beta" page is (currently, for me) the first hit on a search for the phrase "how to ask" from the main help page. https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=how+to+ask

Comment: I just found this page too and came to ask for it to be removed. Why has it not been removed yet? It's hard enough getting new users to read the help section without having useless and confusing pages in there too!

Comment: I have got the same question today. and came here to ask and found this question.

Comment: Corresponding MSE post about the same thing: [“How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” is listed in every site’s help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/335251)

Answer (score 3):

This has been implemented. The `/help/how-to-ask-beta` page will no longer show up on non-beta sites (on the main help page, on the category listing, or the category sidebar), and going to the URL on a non-beta site will result in a 404.

> how-to-ask-beta
> not relevant on a site
> that is not beta