# Butterknife listed twice in open source libraries credits

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, stack-overflow-app

[image: open source libraries credits]

I think that last one should say jmustache as the header instead of butter knife.

Comment: It's not that Butterknife is listed twice, but that JMustache is titled "Butterknife". It was probably copypasted from the old SE app, which has the [same issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280117/164356).

Comment: That question was asked 11 months ago and still nobody cared / had time to fix the credits (which is literally just changing a string). Instead we get a dedicated SO app with all of the same issues of the SE app (and even a bunch more).

Comment: [It isn't just the app that is affected by simple changes that no one bothers to fix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342473/remove-how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-from-the-help-center)

Comment: What is "Butterknife"/"butterknife" (in this context)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen A boilerplate reducing library for native Android development. See [this repo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! Copy pasting so many times led me to totally looking past it.

This is fixed as of version 1.0.2, live now. It'll also be fixed in the Stack Exchange app as of the next update (1.0.95), which isn't live yet.