# Misleading advice in "contact us" page for users with review privileges (500+ rep)

Tags: bug, help-center

**Note: the below is relevant for users with 500+ reputation, who have review icon instead of help center icon in the top bar.**

In the Help Center contact form (which is now made less reachable with the new footer, but that's a separate issue) there is such advice:

> If you have a question about a Stack Exchange site, the best place to ask is on Meta Stack Exchange or the site's own meta. (**Look under "help" on the top bar**.)

See the bold part? That's no longer true. Let's take a look:

> [image]

Do you see "help" anywhere in the top bar? No, unless you have special glasses that look back in time, before the fancy icons were introduced, replacing text links.

Please either change the help center advice to something like "Look under the Stack Exchange menu by clicking the icon that looks like Stack Exchange logo" (sorry can't make it shorter as that's the only way to explain what icon to click), or put textual "help" link again so that people will be able to reach it faster.

**Note: in case the help center contents are static and can't be changed per-site please don't make this change cross-network as long as the new top bar is not applied there.**

Comment: *that's the only way to explain what icon to click* - How about just "Right-most icon".

Comment: But it  doesn't really make sense to change it while every other site does still have the old nav bar. The text preceding it implies that the user might be trying to ask a question about a Stack Exchange site other than Stack Overflow. (Otherwise it would talk about Meta Stack Overflow, not Meta Stack Exchange.)

Comment: [Obviously nobody maintains the Help Center anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342473/remove-how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-from-the-help-center).

Comment: @CodyGray not relevant. The help center is the same on all sites, so they must put content that fits all sites. This is a good point though,  I'll mention in the bug report that as long as the help center contents are static, better wait until the new top bar is applied on all sites.

Comment: @BSMP at some point this new top bar will be applied on all sites. Maybe several years, and there will be newer top bar here in SO by then, but still.

Comment: You say "not relevant", then go on to explain how it is relevant because Stack Overflow has its own, unique top bar design. Hmm. Also, the relevance is that simple bugs and typos are not fixed after *months* of being reported, with the obvious conclusion being that nobody cares to maintain it anymore. Don't get your hopes up about this getting addressed.

Comment: @Cody based on that the team don't care about anything, but that not true.  Coming from MSE I'm used to bug reports and feature requests buried for years without a grain of attention from the team. But that's just part of how this place works, they still do things, even is slow, so we need to report and ask. As for "not relevant", well, maybe didn't explain it well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard looks like that page is customisable as it mentions "Support for Jobs" which isn't present on that page for other sites but it's not mod editable so would take a staff member to change. I'm guessing changing it is going to be much less difficult than trying to think up reasonable wording ;-)

Comment: I'm not against changing the wording once the top bar on other sites is updated. It just doesn't make sense to change the wording of how to find the help link on sites other than Stack Overflow when it hasn't changed anywhere else.

Comment: @JonClements - Isn't it every other site that needs to change if the instructions are about how to find the form on SE sites *other* than the one you're currently on? All the others need the existing instructions + how to find the link on Stack Overflow.

Comment: And also ... damn, the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page in the new footer links to the "Stack Overflow Business Solutions" and not to the help center. I've linked to that in many of the mod messages and the users must have thought which dumb moderator is this. :|

Comment: @BhargavRao old links still work, the link in the new footer is to a different page. Unless you mean you said "click the contact us in the footer", in which case it is just extra click away. It sucks, probably I'll submit new feature request once the new footer is shipped network wide.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, the mod template is something like that. So it's two clicks now instead of one.

Comment: The three layered icons like that tend to be called Hamburger menu icons.  Although this one looks like a cross between that and a speech buble.

Comment: Back a while ago, when I got mad and decided to write an angry blog, and @Shog9 said *"we can't read everything on meta, that's the community...if you have something that's a real problem, bring it to us first, there's 'contact us'..."* but yeah, looks like you can only write business inquiries for jobs or something.  I'm not thrilled having the model be like those businesses where you're a customer, and can't get a person on the line...instead having to go through a phone tree and pretend like you want to sign up for new service to talk to someone.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf no hamburger or beef, that's the actual and real logo of Stack Exchange, been like that from the very beginning. :)

Comment: "that's the only way to explain what icon to click" You can completely remove "icon that looks like"

Comment: Low-rep user view - I've got a help icon in place of the one second from right on your screen, which does indeed have a link to Meta.

Comment: @LogicalFlaps might have to make a new account to test this. new account created, can confim that there is a help icon with useful links. seems this icon is replaced with the review queues when hitting 500 rep

Comment: @LogicalFlaps lol, good point, totally forgot about  it! Edited.

Comment: @BhargavRao That's intentional. We have so many teams and so many ways to contact us that it doesn't make sense for the old /contact page to be the front runner anymore, and we were getting a lot of stuff coming through our inbox that just had to be forwarded elsewhere because no one knew the other options. That page in turn links to the appropriate page for general support.