# Make how-to-ask more prominent

Tags: feature-request, help-center

The ["How do I ask a good question?" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (or *"The absolute minimum every software developer should know about asking others for help (no excuses!)"*) is pretty well hidden.

When not currently asking a question, you need to search for the Help Center:

[image: Ah, there it is!]

Then you have to click the ">> View more" link to find all topics about asking a question, and then [at the bottom of that list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), the `[ask]` page is linked.

When you *are* asking a question, its title is obscured:

[image: "asking help", really?]

It should be more prominently displayed, and accurately titled. Something like this:

[image: Where?]

And when asking a question, why not display its full title (*"How do I ask a good question?"*) instead of "asking help"?

Comment: Isn't it plastered in one's face when one creates an account? If the user doesn't read it then, why would they read it later? But I agree. The help-section has become somewhat hidden.

Comment: @J.Steen Yes, it's shown if you create an account. And then people scroll down to the bottom and click "I agree", without reading. Years of illegible EULA's have conditioned them that way.

Comment: @J.Steen I don't know (don't ask that many questions on Main ;-), but I think at least the asking page should display it with its full title. I'd bet it attracts more clicks than "asking help".

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yeah, that was my point. Maybe the 'agree'-button should have a five minute delay. ;)

Comment: A simple solution is just to change the content in the yellow box right to the question view. A decent summary of how-to-ask ... That's the only thing you can do because lots of people just don't look at it, even not clicking it. If the text is short and clear, then the chance that it's being read is kinda higher

Comment: Yeah, maybe this improvement can be a part of [overhauling the Ask Question page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page). The ["user surveys" have already "gotten underway"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth)...

Comment: Don't bother. They won't read it. Just downvote a lot.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: And does anyone go back to read the EULA later? Nope.

Comment: for users below 500 rep instead of the review icon they have the help centre, made a new account to test [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351908/misleading-advice-in-contact-us-page-for-users-with-review-privileges-500-re#comment490710_351908) yesterday this includes some shortcuts to needed pages, the how to ask page can easily go in there

Comment: Maybe try `<marquee></marquee>`?

Comment: @J.Steen The information here isn't something that you look at once and then never need to see again.  Much of the information there is stuff that people asking questions will want to refer back to if they haven't asked in a while, would want to look back if a question is poorly received and they want to learn how to improve it, etc.  Of course, most users won't use it, that's reality, we know that, but that's not a reason to make it really difficult on the few good users that really care and want to do well, by making the information hard to find, *even for those looking for it*.

Comment: @Servy Did I say "let's keep it hidden"? No, but I *was* cynically saying it likely won't help to make it less so. I guess I'm not as positive as you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to many people saying that "no one reads that anyway", I think this is a good idea.

When *any* help-related link appears *anywhere*, if I don't need it at the moment, I am not going to click it. This principle applies twice:

1. When not asking a question (e.g. when creating an account), links like "asking help" or "How to ask" are irrelevant
2. When asking a question, *asking help* looks irrelevant (even though it's actually very relevant!); however, *How do I ask a good question?* looks somewhat relevant

I think that *How do I ask a good question?* is not the best wording yet. Trying to think as a novice that desperately needs help:

> *How do I ask a good question?* - I don't want to ask a good question! This is the question I have, and I need it answered!!!

The person here doesn't understand that his question can be presented in different ways, and the best way requires experience or guidance. He also doesn't understand that the rules (how to ask a question) try to benefit the *user*, by making it easier for the community to answer the question. This is a difficult concept to grasp, and new users don't get it yet.

Maybe we need a more "practical" wording, like

- How to maximize my chance for good answers?
- How do I get a good answer?
- How to ensure my question will be answered?

Comment: The user in your example is a lost cause.  There is nothing you could possibly do that is going to get that person to ask an appropriate question.  The person you want to have in mind when constructing this page is someone who is more than willing to follow the rules, and include the information we want them to include, and find the right place to ask their question, but just doesn't know what the expectations are (mostly because the expectations here are so different from so many other sites on the internet).  The help page exists for the person who wants to do good but doesn't know how.

Comment: Maybe the additional bits I presented distract from what I am trying to say. I'll remove them.

Comment: I stand by the point.  A user that says, "I don't give a damn about you or your site, just answer the ****ing question" isn't someone who's going to even look at the headers of the help center article to see the difference between, "How do I ask a good question?" and "How do I get a good answer?"  A user like that is beyond being helped.  There is no help center article in existence that will make them ask a good question.  They aren't your target audience.

Comment: I think my post describes a different user.